# Crash using SKProductDiscount's NumberFormatter (_unconditionallyBridgeFromObjectiveC)

Tags: ios, swift, locale, storekit

Using this code that is officially handed by Apple in their documentation :

```swift
extension SKProductDiscount {
    var localizedPrice: String {
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = .currency
        formatter.locale = self.priceLocale  // Line #15 - this is where it crashes
        return formatter.string(from: self.price) ?? ""
    }
}
```

I have users crashing and according to Crashlytics, this is the stack trace:

[image]

What surprises me is that everything in this code is just StoreKit. I have tried changing to different locales, but I can't find how to make this crash happen.

FYI, it happens to a product that has a free introductory offer. So the formatted output string is "[€,$,etc]0.00".

What is this `static Locale._unconditionallyBridgeFromObjectiveC(_:)` causing the crash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an Apple bug which was fixed in iOS 12. The only choice for iOS 11 is to not rely on this dynamic localization but on some homemade logic...